# Python pandas: how to create a column which is a fixed date + the # days in another column

Tags: python, pandas, date

I need to add a column to a dataframe, so that row 0 is 15-Feb-2019. row 1 is 16th, etc. I have tried using the index:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame()
df['a']=np.arange(10,20)
df['date from index']=df.apply( lambda x: pd.to_datetime('15-2-2019') + pd.DateOffset(days=x.index), axis=1 )
```

but I get:

> TypeError: ('must be str, not int', 'occurred at index 0')

which I admit I do not understand.
I tried creating an explicit column to use instead of the index:

```
df=pd.DataFrame()
df['a']=np.arange(10,20)
df['counter']=np.arange(0,df.shape[0])
df['date from counter']=df.apply( lambda x: pd.to_datetime('15-2-2019') + pd.DateOffset(days=x['counter']), axis=1 )
```

but this gives me:

> TypeError: ('unsupported type for timedelta days component:
>   numpy.int32', 'occurred at index 0')

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Thank you, both! Just for my understanding, what was I doing wrong in my example?

Comment: Edited my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html) for convert values to day timedeltas or use 
parameter `origin` with specify start day with parameter `unit` in [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html):

```
df['date from index']= pd.to_datetime('15-2-2019') + pd.to_timedelta(df.index, 'd')
df['date from counter']= pd.to_datetime('15-2-2019') + pd.to_timedelta(df['counter'], 'd')

df['date from index1']= pd.to_datetime(df.index, origin='15-02-2019', unit='d')
df['date from counter1']= pd.to_datetime(df['counter'], origin='15-02-2019', unit='d')
print(df.head())
    a  counter date from index date from counter date from index1  \
0  10        0      2019-02-15        2019-02-15       2019-02-15   
1  11        1      2019-02-16        2019-02-16       2019-02-16   
2  12        2      2019-02-17        2019-02-17       2019-02-17   
3  13        3      2019-02-18        2019-02-18       2019-02-18   
4  14        4      2019-02-19        2019-02-19       2019-02-19   

  date from counter1  
0         2019-02-15  
1         2019-02-16  
2         2019-02-17  
3         2019-02-18  
4         2019-02-19
```

Answer (score 2):

You can vectorise this with `pd.to_timedelta`:

```
# pd.to_timedelta(df.index, unit='d') + pd.to_datetime('15-2-2019') # whichever
pd.to_timedelta(df.a, unit='d') + pd.to_datetime('15-2-2019')

0   2019-02-25
1   2019-02-26
2   2019-02-27
3   2019-02-28
4   2019-03-01
5   2019-03-02
6   2019-03-03
7   2019-03-04
8   2019-03-05
9   2019-03-06
Name: a, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

---

```
df['date_from_counter'] = (
    pd.to_timedelta(df.a, unit='d') + pd.to_datetime('15-2-2019'))
df

    a  counter date_from_counter
0  10        0        2019-02-25
1  11        1        2019-02-26
2  12        2        2019-02-27
3  13        3        2019-02-28
4  14        4        2019-03-01
5  15        5        2019-03-02
6  16        6        2019-03-03
7  17        7        2019-03-04
8  18        8        2019-03-05
9  19        9        2019-03-06
```

As expected, you can call `pd.to_timedelta` on whatever column of integers with the right unit, and then use the resultant `Timedelta` column for date time arithmetic.

---

For your code to work, it seems like you needed to pass `int`, not `np.int` (not sure why). This works.

```
dt = pd.to_datetime('15-2-2019')
df['date from counter'] = df.apply(
    lambda x: dt + pd.DateOffset(days=x['counter'].item()), axis=1)
df

    a  counter date from counter
0  10        0        2019-02-15
1  11        1        2019-02-16
2  12        2        2019-02-17
3  13        3        2019-02-18
4  14        4        2019-02-19
5  15        5        2019-02-20
6  16        6        2019-02-21
7  17        7        2019-02-22
8  18        8        2019-02-23
9  19        9        2019-02-24
```